# Animation with Popups Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

At the starting of 'zoomIn' animation the `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` comes along with it but what I am trying is to popup box to have zoomIn animation and the `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` should already be there.

And I am trying to implement smooth animation of 'backOutTop' after clicking Submit button in the popup box but:
1) The animation is not smooth, it happens very suddenly.
2) After the animation the popup box doesn't seem to hide even after I have set `visibility: hidden;`

If there's any other way to do that. Please do share. Thank You.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".popUp").css('visibility', 'visible')
  }, 500); //Automatically Pops up after 0.5 sec.

});

document.querySelector('.btn-name').addEventListener('click', () => {

  document.querySelector('#popUpid').classList.remove('popUp');
  document.querySelector('#popUpid').classList.add('popUpClose');

});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popUp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 101;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: zoomIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.popUpClose {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: backOutUp;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.popUpBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFF00, #00FF00);
}

.btn-name {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="popUp" id="popUpid">
    <div class="popUpBox">
      <button class="btn-name">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <h1>
      Content
    </h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the question explanation, these are the little changes you need to do in your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        setTimeout(() => {
            $(".popUp").css('visibility', 'visible')
        }, 500); //Automatically Pops up after 0.5 sec.
        
        $('.btn-name').click(function() {
            $('#popUpid').addClass('popUpClose');
        });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .popUp {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 101;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        animation: zoomIn;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    .popUpClose {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: backOutUp;
        animation-duration: 3s;
    }

    .popUpBox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFF00, #00FF00);
    }

    .btn-name {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="popUp" id="popUpid">
            <div class="popUpBox">
                <button class="btn-name">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="wrapper">
            <h1>
                Content
            </h1>
        </section>
```

for your still background and animation only on popUP.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        setTimeout(() => {
            $(".popUpBox").addClass('show');
            
        }, 500); //Automatically Pops up after 0.5 sec.
        
        $('.btn-name').click(function() {
            $('#popUpid').addClass('popUpClose');
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(".popUp").css('opacity','0');
        }, 1800);
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .popUp {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 101;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .popUpClose {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: backOutUpCustom;
        animation-duration: 3s;
    }

    .popUpBox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0,0);
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        transition: all 3s;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFF00, #00FF00);
    }
    .popUpBox.show {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1,1);
    }
    .btn-name {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    @keyframes backOutUpCustom {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1,1);
        opacity: 1
    }

    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) scale(0.7,0.7);
        transform: translate(-50%, 0) scale(0.7,0.7);
        opacity: .7
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -700px) scale(0.7,0.7);
        transform: translate(-50%, -700px) scale(0.7,0.7);
        opacity: .7
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="popUp">
            <div class="popUpBox" id="popUpid">
                <button class="btn-name">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="wrapper">
            <h1>
                Content
            </h1>
        </section>
```

Comment: if this will help you, don't forget to mark it as right answer.

Comment: Just a side note, it is better to specify 'transition' and not use 'all' as per device rendering and CPU usage. It tends to build up and lead to problems on low and middle-end devices.

Comment: @Atul These are the exact changes I need. I just wanted to ask that can we handle background, it comes along with animation but instead how can we set the background and make the popup box animation to happen on it? I don't want to be heard as greedy but I described this part in question. Otherwise Thank You So Much. You have been a great help.

Comment: changing it as per your requirements, sit tight, just one question, you don't want any kind of animation or effect on the background part? it just comes and goes instantly with set timeout and submit click? or you always want to show grey background?

Comment: When the pop up comes, I want gray shade to be there on the background that overlaps on the content part. And hence we focus on popup and its animation that happens on the grey shade of bakcground.

Comment: Thank you @Atul.

Comment: your welcome, is that it? or you want to fix the going animaton on your background as well, as its not looking good to me,LOL

Comment: Check now, its better now